# Socket.io - old version of app.js to new version socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, arduino

i look in the code from [GitHUB - Arduino Serialport Socket.io](https://github.com/indiejoseph/arduino-node.js-serialport-socket.io) and everything is ok. Its work as good as it should. This project contains (from package.json):

```
"dependencies": {
    "serialport": "*",
    "socket.io": "0.9.6"},
"engines": { "node": "0.6" }
```

But when I copy app.js and /web/index.html and I want to install new package by doing

```
npm install serialport --save
npm install socket.io --save
npm install node --save
```

I get in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "serialport": "~2.0.2",
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7",
    "node": "0.0.0",}
```

As you see the verion is not the same. And the program is not working. It seems like the socket.io don't start. Serialport send data to terminal and webpage is working but no data receive from socket.
Terminal (old socket - it work):

```
user@user-K52Jc:~/sio$ node app.js
Server started on localhost:3000
   info  - socket.io started
Port opened... Press reset on the Arduino.
serial port: A474B
```

Terminal (new socket - it NOT work):

```
user@user-K52Jc:~/ArdWEB_POT$ node app.js
Server started on localhost:3000
Port opened... Press reset on the Arduino.
serial port: A474B
```

Can anyone can help me with this problem ? Help

BTW. In chrome Ctrl+ Shift+C open console and it give log error:

> GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1446114714737-4 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

May by it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the problem. I download many of apps and now i know the answer. 
Problem is in that line in index.html

```
var socket = io.connect("/", {
```

it must be:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/", {
```